# How to convert HTML(JSON, Ajax ) into C# WinForm?

Tags: ajax, winforms

I'd like to convert following HTML(json, ajax) Code in C# Winform application.

I'll try it by using JSON.Net, but I'm not familiar with C# WinForm. 
I want to binding ajax result value after the user click a button. 
How do I this??

html code following that : 
Thank you.

---

```
// format string 
function J2String(object) {
    var results = [];
    for (var property in object) {

        var value = object[property];

        if (value != null){
            results.push(property.toString() + ': ' + value ); 
        } 
    }                            
    return '{' + results.join(', ') + '}';
}

// format ajax result data 
formatstring = function (text) {
    if (arguments.length <= 1) return text; 

    for (var i = 0; i <= arguments.length - 2; i++) {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gi"), 
               arguments[i + 1]);
    }
    return text;
}

// return data [ GET method ]  
function GetAjaxData(){
    RcvData.value = "";
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1", 
        type:"GET",
        data: { "REQ": formatstring ("AA^^1000^^^^23^1234567^W1234567890^^00000081") },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        success: function(data){
            RcvData.value = J2String(data); 
        }
    });
}  
<body> 
Value : <input type="text" style="width:80%" id="RcvData"><br/>
<form name="tform" method="post">
<input type="button" value="Send"  onClick="GetAjaxData()" >
</body>
```

---

Comment: [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ .net framework 4.5 ] 
~~~ using ~~ ;  
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; 


private async void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
    string reqData = "AA^^1000^^^^23^1234567^W1234567890^^00000081"; 
    textBox1.Text = await GetAjaxData(reqData);  
}   


private async Task<string> GetAjaxData(string reqData){ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/?callback=jsonp123456&REQ=" + reqData );

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
    byte[] buf = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); 
    Encoding myEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"); 
    string data = myEncoding.GetString(buf, 0, buf.Length - 1); 

    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data );  

    string _parseData = obj.Code 
                      + "^" + obj.Name
                      + "^" + obj.RespCode
                      + "^" + obj.Remark; 

    var result = await Task.FromResult<string>(_parseData);

    return result;  
}
```